# Sort vs OrderBy c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, lambda

I want to update this code to use OrderBy instead of Sort.

```
 protected void Sort()
        {
            m_Items.Sort(new Comparison<PayArrayItem>(
                delegate (PayArrayItem x, PayArrayItem y)
                {
                    return x.TransactionDate.CompareTo(y.TransactionDate);
                }
                ));
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of  `m_Items`?

Comment: `m_Items.OrderBy(m => m.TransactionDate)`

Comment: List<PayArrayItem >

Comment: `Sort` will be sorting the list *in situ*, which means it will actually change the list itself, whereas `OrderBy` will return a new (sorted) List (to be precise: an IEnumerable). This fits into the general theme of LINQ and functional programming, I guess it would help you to find a tutorial about LINQ in general to understand the differences completely.

Comment: Since question already have solid copy-paste ready answer I voted to close it as duplicate of more general comparison of Sort vs. OrderBy which shows all kinds of syntax along with explaining differences for each approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Sort` does *in place* sorting, i.e. it sorts *existing* `m_Items` collection:

```
protected void Sort() {
  m_Items.Sort((left, right) => left.TransactionDate.CompareTo(right.TransactionDate));
}
```

On the contrary, *Linq* `OrderBy` creates a *new* `IEnumerable<T>` which you have to *materialize* and *assign* back to the collection:

```
using System.Linq;

...

protected void Sort() {
  m_Items = m_Items
    .OrderBy(item => item.TransactionDate)
    .ToList(); // Assuming m_Items is List<T>
}
```

Please, note, that since in case of `OrderBy` we create an *additional* `List<T>` instance, that's why `Sort` is better choice in your case.